# Final Cut Pro 10.4.3 Mojave Compatibility

Tags: mojave, final-cut-pro

I'm having some compatibility issues in macOS Mojave.
I can't see the thumbnails preview of Titles, Effects, etc.

Is there any known fix for this?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Maybe it's something related with OpenGL: [Some things that broke in Mojave OpenGL](https://twitter.com/icculus/status/1054634481812992000)

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Mojave on the weekend and FCP works fine for me. I'm running FCP 10.4.4. Maybe you should update to that version?

I can't recall when I updated FCP, but it was before upgrading to Mojave. Good luck! :-)